# Anylogic error when connecting Excel-database: "Event Loop Exception null"

Tags: excel, database-connection, anylogic

Whenever I want to connect an Excel-database the following error message pops up:

Event Loop Exception
null

It happens when I want to access the Excel-file by "Database - Create or import a table..." and also when I want to access it by an agent population.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: I got that on my macbook, on windows it doesn't happen... I think it's just a bug

Comment: Actually, I use windows. The pevious days it was working properly... But yes, probably it's a bug

Comment: should not be a problem on Windows. Can you share more details and screenshots. What exactly do you do, what does the xls file look like... have you tried to recreate the issue with a simple file?

Comment: I also once had this problem, closing anylogic and excel, deleting all the database and restarting my computer did fix this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, it happens on windows. I used this setting several times: 1) emty and new model 2) simplest xls datatable in MS Excel 365 and also MS Excel 2013 with two columns (name and age) and three rows of names and ages. I also closed all models, restated Anylogic (Research License) and the computer, but the problem still occurs.

Comment: Did you also try to experiment with the location of excel file and anylogic model, perhaps a problem is there if it happens with all your models

Comment: I now tried it also myself, and the strange thing is I got the same error, but the excelsheet still seems to load in?

Comment: That's odd. I tried to access the file from different locations but it doesn't change anything. However, when closing the software and removing the workspace folder (for Windows) "C:\Users\<username>\.AnyLogicProfessional\Workspace8.7" it works once. But after that it is no working anymore.

Comment: @Philipp do you not see any database at all in Anylogic after the error? I think it is really somewhere in the folder management.

Comment: Yes, connecting is successful once. The second time I want to import a table the error message appears already when selecting the file and then it can't be uploaded.

Comment: Perhaps you can upload the anylogic file and the database, if it works fine for me, it will probably be a software error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted Anylogic and it is a known bug, they will fix it by the new release, to solve it the quick fix is:
As for now, there is a workaround - you may close AnyLogic, clear Workspace8.7 folder (C:\Users<username>.AnyLogicEditionName\Workspace8.7), and try importing data again.

Answer (score 0):

This bug delayed my research work for about 2 days. Luckily, I had an older version of Anylogic (8.7.3) on one of my old laptops. That's what I'm using now. Download the older version of Anylogic (without this bug) from the link below:

https://files.mycloud.com/home.php?seuuid=fa53e0c5f116ed57167a468c527bf8bd&name=Anylogic%20874&brand=webfiles

Alternative Link:
https://home.mycloud.com/action/share/442fbbea-7acd-410f-aabb-f0edc9a0a62d

Comment: Perhaps it is an idea to contact anylogic and tell them about the bug